# Database driven template context with MPTT: how to represent lists vs dictionaries?

Tags: python, django, mptt

I've run into many situations where I'd like some database driven arbitrarily nested template context. This content is always pretty simple but varies highly in structure.

In the past I've created models for tiny sections of the website which quickly becomes bit of a nightmare to maintain as the model count goes up and I start repeating myself for every little area of editable content. The admin gets full of inlines each for one specific piece.

To solve this I'd like to create a simple DB driven context model. I will probably create a small framework like django's admin to generate the default structure for a given purpose.

My current model basically looks like so:

```
class DBContext(MPTTModel):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    key = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    value = models.TextField(blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='dbcontext/files/', blank=True, null=True)
```

From this model I can easily create an arbitrary depth python dictionary. The question is how to best differentiate between a list and a dictionary for child nodes: a single dictionary as a child, a list of values as children, or list of dictionaries as children.

#### An extra `type` field that children are coerced into?

```
class DBContext(MPTTModel):
    NONE = 0
    LIST = 1
    DICTIONARY = 2
    COERCE_TYPES = [
        (NONE, 'None'),
        (LIST, 'Children as list'), # ignore keys.
        (DICTIONARY, 'Children as Dictionary'),
    ]
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    key = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    value = models.TextField(blank=True)
    coerce_type = models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=COERCE_TYPES)

    def to_python(self):
        # when converting to python, any children of a node would be coerced into the value_type type


# Converted to python:
{
    'foo': { # coerce_type == DICTIONARY
        'child_node_as_dict': '',
    },
    'bar': [ # coerce_type == LIST
        'child_node_as_list',
    ],
    'baz': [ # coerce_type == LIST
        { # coerce_type == DICTIONARY
            'child_node_list_of_dicts': '',
        },
    ],
}
```

#### Determine via children keys?

- If all children share the same key, it's a list. Ignore keys.
- If there's one+ children it's a dictionary.
- If there are no children, it's a string.

Any suggestions?

PS: the only reason I'm not pickling is because I'm using the admin to handle editing this data to start with and I haven't really explored replacing `FileField`. Truth is I haven't looked too deeply into storages. Basically my motivation here is to create something useful quickly. This system works in about 5 minutes "bone stock" if I force all children to be dictionary items and solves our problems when it comes to making random areas of our website admin editable.

Comment: I'm starting to dig into a clean way to implement a pickled field that supports instantiating `FileFields` / uploading files to a FileField storage.

Comment: Update:  I've solved my nested dict/list problem by using a YAML field. It allows arbitrary complexity, even has reference pointers, and can represent any python structure of any depth.